Build app by multiple environments in Flutter using Android Studio/Xcode
I need to run my Flutter app in multiple backend environments. For instance
DEV environment -> my backend url is https://dev.com

PRO environment -> https://pro.com.

I use Android Studio/Xcode to config build type for each environment (dev/pro) and build into apk/ipa. The problem is I have no idea on how the config for flutter code is relevant to the config in Android Studio/Xcode. What is the right way to solve my problem? Can anyone explain me what I need to do?
This is my config in Android Studio
buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
        dev {
            initWith release
            applicationIdSuffix ".dev"
        }
        pro {
            initWith release
        }
    }


There are typically two methods:

Create different main.dart files for different environments, such as main_dev.dart and main_pro.dart.
Use a method channel. Flutter provides a way to save the environment, and the native code can call this method.


With the first method, if I build an apk with pro build type in Android Studio, how flutter knows to use the main_pro.dart. Can you explain me with this? @Nullable

And could you refer me some documents about the idea in the second method you said. I haven't found some things as your idea is :(( @Nullable

You can refer to this documentation: https://docs.flutter.dev/add-to-app/android/project-setup.
